# installing sklearn version 0.18.1 in Apache web server

Tags: python, apache, flask, scikit-learn

I am trying to install the latest version (0.18.1) of sklearn for use in a web app

I am hosting my webapp with apache web server and flask

I have tried sudo apt-get -y install python3-sklearn and this works but installs an older version of sklearn (0.17)

I have also tried pip3 and easy_install and these complete the install but are not picked up by flask or apache.

I get the following error log on my apache server

[Thu Dec 29 13:07:45.505294 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 31371:tid 140414290982656] [remote 90.201.35.82:25030]     from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
[Thu Dec 29 13:07:45.505315 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 31371:tid 140414290982656] [remote 90.201.35.82:25030] ImportError: cannot import name 'GaussianProcessRegressor'

This is because I am trying to access some features of sklearn which are not present in 0.17 but are there in 0.18.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use anaconda. It will save you so much time with these annoying dependency issues.

Comment: unfortunately the current version of anaconda comes with scikit-learn version 0.17.1 and I am after 0.18.1

Comment: Yes but you can conda update scikit-learn and it will update to 0.18.1. And I am using it so can confirm it works.